# Autofilter on VBA

Tags: vba, excel, reporting, autofilter

I am trying to apply an Autofilter for one column, however i do not want to restrict the filter by giving specific value. I want excel to filter the values automatically one by one. Basically I am creating macro to filter a column with certain value & then paste that unique data in another sheet, in simple words need to segregate the data. 
Eg:

```
Column A
Ab
Bc
Cd
De
Ef
```

I want excel to filter the values one by one. Like first **AB**, then copy the data & paste in a new sheet. Then automatically go to next value which is **BC** & copy. Similarly to the next value. Can anyone help?

Comment: what have you actually tried to get this done? please post your code attempt and we can help you clean it up where it's not working. Also what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @jeeped - I am concerned that the duplicate question is far more complicated than this one. I would think a simple loop through unique values, filter, copy / paste would suffice here.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Yes, but I only give myself ten minutes to locate duplicates (when I **know** that I have answered the question before). I have no wish to look all day for the exact duplicate when the OP clearly has not done any research of their own. They need to build a unique list (Scripting Dictionary) and it is easier to copy the master list each time (and subsequently delete all non-matches) then copy matches to a new worksheet and perform all of the formatting.

Comment: @jeeped - fair enough my friend. understood.

Comment: I have written the code on my office desktop & cannot access the website as it is restricted. I will post the code i have written.